# unexpected Output in map function using javascript / node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
let array1 =
[["/home/animal","carnivours"],
 ["/home/cow","milk"],
 ["/home/plant","small"],
 ["/home/fish","tank"]];
 
 
 let array2= 
 [{
  id:01,
  name:"/home/cow"
 },
 {
  id:02,
  name:"/home/fish"
}];
 
 array2.map((data)=>{
 let check = array1.find((x)=>x[0]==data.name);
 let result= check.map((x)=>x[1]);
 console.log(result); 
 });
```

I was expecting my output as `tank` and `milk` but I don't know why i got this strange output where i am doing wrong i don't get it

Comment: `check.map((x)=>x[1])` takes the first item (first character) of each item in the list that you picked from your bigger list. — You don’t need `map` here, since you’re not trying to create a new list!

Comment: then how ill i get `tank` and `milk` @deceze ?

Comment: With just `check[1]`.

Comment: got it thank you :) @deceze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need you map `check` all you need is to take the element in position 1 in `check`

```js
let array1 =
[["/home/animal","carnivours"],
 ["/home/cow","milk"],
 ["/home/plant","small"],
 ["/home/fish","tank"]];
 
 
 let array2= 
 [{
  id:01,
  name:"/home/cow"
 },
 {
  id:02,
  name:"/home/fish"
}];
 
 array2.map((data)=>{
 let check = array1.find((x)=>x[0]==data.name);
 let result= check[1];
 console.log(result); 
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the code a bit here and just access the matching `find()` directly

```
let result = array2.map(data => array1.find((x) => x[0] === data.name))
```

```js
let array1 = [
  ["/home/animal", "carnivours"],
  ["/home/cow", "milk"],
  ["/home/plant", "small"],
  ["/home/fish", "tank"]
];

let array2 = [{id: 01, name: "/home/cow"},
  {id: 02, name: "/home/fish"}];

let result = array2.map(data => array1.find((x) => x[0] === data.name)[1])
console.log(result);
```

Comment: it's coming in form of array i was using map function to fetch data single and in string format